# SIFLess installation error "ERROR_SCRIPTDOM_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER

Tags: sitecore-install-framework

At the time of installing Sitecore 9 by using SIFLess-EZ Power-shell script, the below error is obtained.

```
"ERROR_SCRIPTDOM_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER ".
```

IN Dev m/c I have VS 2013, 2015 and 2017 insatlled with .NET v4.7
SQL Server:- 2016 and 2012.

I referred  blog "https://naveed-ahmad.com/2017/11/03/sitecore-9-sif-installation-error-error_scriptdom_needed_for_sql_provider/" but still same issue.

[image]

> [WebDeploy]:[Path] C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy
>   V3\msdeploy.exe msdeploy.exe : Error Code:
>   ERROR_SCRIPTDOM_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER At C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\1.2.1\Public\Tasks\Invoke-CommandTask.ps1:31
>   char:13
>   +             & $Path $Arguments | Out-Default
>   +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Error Code: ERR...OR_SQL_PROVIDER:String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError msdeploy.exe : Error Code: ERROR_SCRIPTDOM_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER At C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\1.2.1\Public\Tasks\Invoke-CommandTask.ps1:31
>   char:13
>   +             & $Path $Arguments | Out-Default
>   +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Error Code: ERR...OR_SQL_PROVIDER:String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
>
> More Information: The SQL provider cannot run because of a missing
>   dependency. Please make sure that Microsoft SQL  Server Transact-SQL
>   ScriptDom is installed.  Learn more at: 
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_SCRIPTDOM_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROV
>   More Information: The SQL provider cannot run because of a missing
>   dependency. Please make sure that Microsoft SQL Server Transact-SQL
>   ScriptDom is installed.  Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_SCRIPTDOM_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROV
>   IDER. IDER.
>
> Error count: 1. Error count: 1.

Comment: Have you tried installing prerequisites that the error message is pointing to: 
Resolution: Use Web Platform Installer to install:

    1. Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Data-Tier Application Framework
    2. SQL Server 2012 Transact-SQL ScriptDom
    3. SQL Server System CLR Types 11.0

Comment: When I am installing "DACFramework.msi" getting error "Installation of microsoft sql server 2012 data-tier app framework failed because a higher version"

Answer (score 5):

This would be because of the SQL provider cannot run because of a missing dependency. Please make sure that Microsoft SQL Server Transact-SQL ScriptDom is installed.

**To resolve the issue:**

- Set the path to the Data-Tier application framework in Windows Registry:

  1. Locate the installation folder of the MS SQL server version that you are using: **\%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SQL Server\**.
  2. Find the Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll file in one of the subfolders: **\DAC\bin** or **\SDK\Assemblies**.
  3. Store the full path to this subfolder as a **DacFxPath** value (String type) under the registry key **\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\MSDeploy\3**.
- Set the path to the SQL ScriptDOM and CLRTypes components in Windows Registry:

  1. Locate the installation folder of the MS SQL server version that you are using: **\%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SQL Server\**.
  2. Find the Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll and Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll files in one of the subfolders: **\DAC\bin** or **\SDK\Assemblies**.
  3. Store the full path to this subfolder as a **DacFxDependenciesPath** value (String type) under the registry key **\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\MSDeploy\3**.

Comment: I know this is old, but just incase someone needs this.... please reboot after doing the regedit update.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

It works after running the CMD as below:

> "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\gacutil" /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\140\Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll"

This registers the `Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll` in Global Assembly Cache (GAC)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, none of the above worked for me.
Installing

> Microsoft SQL Server Data-Tier Application Framework (DACFx) (June
>   2014)

through the "Web Platform Installer" did fix everything though (without having to make any changes to the Registry or GAC).

It should solve all of the following error messages:

```
ERROR_DACFX_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER
ERROR_SCRIPTDOM_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER
ERROR_SQLCLRTYPES_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER
```

Solution found here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/web-deploy-error-codes#ERROR_DACFX_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER (even though it lists an older version).